# A chess problem in Kanamori's "The Higher Infinite"?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, large-cardinals

Just after Corollary 21.17 (on p289) of Kanamori's *The Higher Infinite*, he outlines the direction in which he wants to take his discussion of iterated ultrapowers. However, immediately after he presents a chess problem. The passage reads as follows:

> Having developed the analogue of the $0^\sharp$ theory in §9, we now proceed to derive more information with iterated ultrapowers that sharpens the focus. But first, a respite from the rigors: Instead of yet another recipe, we offer the following chess problem (M. Henneberger, first and second prize, “Revista de Sah” 1928):
>
> White: King on b1, Rooks on b7 and c7, and Bishop on b5.
>
> Black: King on a8, Rook on a3, and Pawn on f2.
>
> White to play and win. Send complete solutions to the author for a small prize.

My question is simply the following; is this just a chess problem, or is there some joke about large cardinals that I am missing?

Comment: Probably, he was in the middle of an untimed chess game while he was writing the book. The board is still sitting there, with all the positions intact, as the author waits patiently for some clever reader to email him a winning strategy.

Comment: Well, that part of the book is pretty dense, and it's nice to change things up for a while.  (I once set up this position in a chess solver and let it run for a while -- a few hours -- without a result, so it's not a trivial position by any means.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a review of the book [here](http://jdh.hamkins.org/bookreviewkanamori/), and it mentions the problem, and gives no indication that it's at all related to the mathematics. I think it's safe to assume you're not missing a joke.

Comment: Surely there are some questions tagged [set-theory] that you can answer; but have you ever thought there will be one tagged [large-cardinals] that you could, and would, answer? :-)

Comment: I owe it all to Google.

Answer (score 4):

I am almost certain it is not a joke.  I have found another reference to the problem [here](http://www.yacpdb.org/?id=294370&rev=1136088), and this also provides a solution (I think).  I couldn't see anything that would indicate to me any connection with $0^\sharp$, but perhaps my powers of imagination are too limited.

Comment: Time to collect my "small prize" from Aki!

Comment: So, did you send him an email?